# Windows phone comnpatbility

Tags: windows-phone-8

How can I run my windows phone 8 application in windows phone 7? I have developed an app in windows phone 8 but when I want to run that app in windows phone 7 it is not running. Is there any way to make my app compatible

Comment: I suggest you create a wp7 project and rewrite your code without longlistselector own or other objects WP8

Comment: It is so Annoying that you are looking for downgrade compatibility of you project. Yes, upgraded compatibility is available in this case. Further more follow the @FrancoisBorgies suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

If the application is written for WP8 you can't run it on WP7. On the other hand, if the application is written for WP7 you can run it on WP8.

If you need to run it on WP7 you must modify your code but there are a lot of improvements in WP8 that maybe you are using in your app but won't be available in your new compilation for WP7.

More information available in https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/jj206947(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

WP8 application can not be run on WP7. although you can run WP7 written code in WP8. 
So i would suggest you to rewrite your code using WP7 SDK that will be compatible for both platform.